# Progressive page loading in ASP.NET MV3?

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building a website that on its frontpage has different 'lists' of stories/articles.
You can compare it to Wordpress 'latest articles', 'spotlight articles' etc.

Now every list needs to be created, and filled from the repository.
Which means, that in my controller, I first create/retrieve all the lists, add them to the ViewBag, and then return the view.

In the View i'll then foreach over the items in that list to create a visual list to be shown on the frontpage.

However, when I load the page, I first get a blank page, when the page is loaded, and then at one point everything appears. 
Traditionally, you would already see the basic html, text etc, and then the dynamic area's would appear later.

**Is it possible to have a similar 'progressive loading' with MVC3?** 
Its not so much the performance I'm worrying about but more so the user experience of seeing a blank page for several seconds on data-heavy pages.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got heavy pages with long loading times you might consider loading the pieces more dynamically using an ajax approach.

Your page loads, you execute the requests for the data you require and use some standard loading icon in the meantime.